# Handling Redirects Between Domains Securely

Tags: c#, security, http, https, load-balancing

I have software that is serving up hundreds of different websites on different URLs via HTTP. However, we are now adding functionality so that users can login and do various other tasks, however this needs to be run via HTTPS, so we've run into a little problem where the user needs to be known on both websites, but we obviously can't set cookies across domains and can only see user credentials via the HTTPS domain. I'm trying to discover the best way to forward credentials onto the HTTPS site for login, but also let the primary domain that the user has logged in.

Comment: Perhaps setup an OpenID server?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, users need to login via accounts native to the application itself.

Comment: That would still work fine, a user can be signed in automatically to the application itself once receiving a valid jwt token. If you mean that users need to provide a unique username/password for each site, well, then, it's not exactly trivial to authenticate across sites. And once you're sharing authentication across sites, it's probably a better idea to have a centralized authentication service.

Comment: Does the customer need to have an OpenID account?

Comment: They would need to have an account on an OpenID server (which you can host yourself, on a private server), but not an account on the OpenID website itself

Comment: what about implementing OAuth?